# Run a task when a list of tasks are completed

Tags: azure-functions

I have a series of files that I need to upload. When each file is uploaded, an operation will be performed on it. When all the files are uploaded, I want to perform a task on all the distinct file types. Technically, the process can run after any file is uploaded, but if I upload a hundred files, I don't want it to run 100 times.

I am using Azure Functions, so this would have to be triggered somehow, either via blob, table, queue or timer triggers (or some other trigger).

Here's my thoughts on how I would accomplish this:

- Push new file to blob storage
- Blob trigger is activated

  - File processed
  - Push file type to table storage
  - Clear queue
  - Push flag to queue with visibility delay of 1 minutes
- Queue triggered, with `IQueryable<TableEntity>` as additional input

  - Get all table entries
  - Perform task on each file type (table entry)
  - Delete processed entries from the table

I'm not super fond of having to keep resetting the queue, but if X files get uploaded in the last one minute of processing, then the next task will run X times, which is wasted resources, especially if X is high. So really, in this case, there should only ever be, at most, one item in the queue.

I keep thinking that a blob trigger with a visibility delay could make more sense, but, as far as I know, that doesn't exist.

So is this the right way to solve this with what is available? Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you explain what the action that you want to run per distinct file type does? Does it update the files? Read the files? Can it be run on the same file more than once?

Comment: Let's say a research lab drops some files. The blob trigger goes through all the new files and standardizes the files. When all of the standardization is complete, we start doing more complex processing and analytics on a per study basis (and there may be multiple studies updated). Could I run the analytics n times for m studies? Probably. But I'd save a ton of money and resources by just processing m times. It also simplifies the monitoring story, so if an error occurs, we aren't getting n errors for the same study.

Comment: I think it is a pretty strange design you are going with. How are you going to be sure that the files uploaded within a 1 minute window belong to the same set of files? What if two researchers are uploading at the same time? 
Maybe you should upload the file sets in different folders or simply upload all files together as a zip (if the file size allows for that)

Comment: I know what files belong to which set based on their filename. Simultaneous uploads is not really an issue. I am operating on certain constraints from the business. I don't control how I get the files, just how I process them.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is that you have some "complete" task that you want to run after the files are uploaded; but there's no explicit "finished uploading" event. You want to optimize better than just having to run the complete task after every file upload.

Here are some options:

1. The [Singleton] attribute (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton ) gives you a way to guarantee a function is only run once (like a distributed lock). So if you spend 100 minutes uploading blobs; and the complete task takes 5 minutes to run; you'd only run it 20 times, not 100 times.
2. There's a preview of Durable Functions, https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension , which allows better orchestration for things like this. Essentially, it lets you do Task.WhenAll on Azure Functions.
3. You could have some delay mechanism that only runs the Complete task after N minutes of no new uploads. The Blob Trigger could a) write to a common receipt blob with the current time, b) push a Queue message with a visibility delay N minutes and contents match the blob receipt. On queue trigger, ignore if the times don't match - since that means another blob upload operation overwrote the receipt during your N minute window, and so that blob upload may be the "last" one.